# Get the value of an HTML element

Tags: c#, regex

I have the HTML code of a webpage in a text file. I'd like my program to return the value that is in a tag. E.g. I want to get "Julius" out of

```
<span class="hidden first">Julius</span>
```

Do I need regular expression for this? Otherwise what is a string function that can do it?

Comment: You do not want regex. HTML is too complex for regex parsing. Here is the infamous answer to that point : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Also what do you actually want? Assuming you don't just want "Julius" returned everytime do you want all text between <span> tags? All text between <span> tags that have a class of "first"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using an html parser like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) .Regex is not a good choice for parsing HTML files as HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format.

You can use below code to retrieve it using `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='hidden first']")//this xpath selects all span tag having its class as hidden first
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();

//itemList now contain all the span tags content having its class as hidden first
```

Comment: No, the C#/.NET regex engine is certainly capable of matching non-[REGULAR](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html#comment_40) expressions. But you are correct that other tools are a better choice for parsing HTML.

Comment: @ridgerunner u r right..i guess `.net` has the best `regex` engine..:D

Answer (score 7):

I would use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse the HTML in C#.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend you look into something like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

Answer (score 1):

i've asked the same question few days ago and ened up using HTML Agility Pack, but here is the regular expressions that you want

this one will ignore the attributes

```
<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>
```

this one will consider the attributes

```
<span class="hidden first"[^>]*>(.*?)</span>
```